# Creating an object of QDeclarativeView results in segmentation fault

Tags: qt, qt-quick

**.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE void cppMethod (const QString &msg) 
  {
    qDebug() << "Called the C++ method with" << msg;
  }

public slots:
  void cppSlot (int number) 
  {
    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with" << number;
  }
};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMetaObject>

#include "cppFromQml.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QDeclarativeView view;

  return a.exec();
}
```

**This results in segmentation fault.** What's the way out?

**Qt: 4.8.1**

Comment: This may be a bug. Try to use a newer version (5.1.1 or 4.8.5).

Comment: Run it in a debugger to see where it crashes. And add `view.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that you're **not** using MyClass, and - just my guess - a declarative view will need a QApplication to properly run.

To better understand, I created a project, dumped almost all away (just kept the .pro, where I added `qt += declarative`), and changed a bit your code as follow:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMetaObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

now it runs and display an empty view, as expected...